# Include a JS file using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, include

I actually have a problem with including JS file using jQuery. I found many sources but no one work with me. I'm pretty sure that the path of the js file is right. These are my two tries :

The first one (which I prefer) is working with `<link>` (to include CSS files) but it's not working with `<script>` tags.

```js
 $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+addon+'"></script>');
```

And the second one is by using get HTTP request. And here is my try :

```js
 $.getScript(addon, function(){});
```

So, the question is: what is wrong with the first code? Because I tried it before with `<link>` tags and its working so good.

Comment: You MUST escape the end tag `<\/script>`

Comment: Do you realize they are both get requests? ;)

Comment: $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+addon+'"><\/script>'); Is it right way to append external js in our head section dynamically

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you considered:

```
$('<script />', { type : 'text/javascript', src : addon}).appendTo('head');
```

This avoids having to manually escape the `</script>` closing tag.

Comment: Good one. Didn't think of that

Comment: @mplungjan: thanks! I like simplicity (when I'm thinking clearly, anyway...) =)

Comment: Thats amazing, guys you're amazing, both solutions were right :D thanks too much!

Comment: You're very welcome, of course; I'm glad to have been of help, and thank *you* for the accept. =)

Comment: @DavidThomas thats the prettiest way I saw to do this..Please refer me to a link where I can get more detail about such a use of jQuery object?..thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You MUST escape the end tag `<\/script>` otherwise you close the scripts prematurely

Answer (score 1):

try `$.holdReady(true);
$.getScript("sample.js", function() {
    $.holdReady(false);
});`

This ensures that your js is fully loaded before the onready object is fired and thus you can be sure that any objects/functions of the dynamically included js are available.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$.when(
    $.getScript( "sample.js" ),
    $.getScript( "simple.js" ),
    $.getScript( "jquery.js" ),
    $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
    $( deferred.resolve );
    })
    ).done(function(){
        //place your code here, the scripts are all loaded
});
```